# How to display list items in columns

Tags: jquery, css, gravity-forms-plugin

I know I can evenly distribute list items across columns using "columns" e.g.

```
<ul style="columns: 3;">
  <li class="left">Data 1</li>
  <li class="left">Data 2</li>
  <li class="left">Data 3</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 4</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 5</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 6</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 7</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 8</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 9</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 10</li>
  <li class="right">Data 11</li>
  <li class="right">Data 12</li>
  <li class="right">Data 13</li>
  <li class="right">Data 14</li>
  <li class="right">Data 15</li>
</ul>
```

"columns" creates this:

```
Data 1   Data 6   Data 11
Data 2   Data 7   Data 12
Data 3   Data 8   Data 13   
Data 4   Data 9   Data 14
Data 5   Data 10  Data 15
```

Instead, I want to format as:

```
Data 1   Data 4   Data 11
Data 2   Data 5   Data 12
Data 3   Data 6   Data 13   
         Data 7   Data 14
         Data 8   Data 15
         Data 9   
         Data 10
```

Can this even be achieved?

I have a pretty good understanding of css and don't see any way to get the column to go up to the top of row 2 and 3 without absolute positioning which becomes problematic with varying heights ... Unless I use jQuery - which I think might be the only way?

Unfortunately, Gravity Forms has no way to define columns and you can't even split into separate lists (which would be easiest) but we can at least add css classes - but I don't even think that will help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use jQuery you could do it like this. I'd be very interested to see if this could be done for a single list with CSS only.

```js
$(".middle").each(incrementOffset);
$(".right").each(incrementOffset);

function incrementOffset(index) {
  var $el = $(this);
  
  var offset = $el.height() * index;
  $el.css("top", offset + "px");
  
  // Increases the size of the list as it won't grow by itself with absolutely positioned items
  var $parent = $el.parent();
  if ($parent.height() < offset + $el.height()) {
    $parent.height(offset + $el.height());
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: #eee; /* to show list height */
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 66%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="left">Data 1</li>
  <li class="left">Data 2</li>
  <li class="left">Data 3</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 4</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 5</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 6</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 7</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 8</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 9</li>
  <li class="middle">Data 10</li>
  <li class="right">Data 11</li>
  <li class="right">Data 12</li>
  <li class="right">Data 13</li>
  <li class="right">Data 14</li>
  <li class="right">Data 15</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. I though this would be the only solution. I tried implementing BUT el.height() is returning 0 for me. I can't see why - no console errors. I'm definitely using the right element (I am showing the element ID prior and it is the right element) - I am thinking it is because it is absolutely positioned (no height) but it works fine for you... so I can't figure it out: http://supportact.oleymedia.com/apply/ (page 2)

Comment: The form starts off display: none; Does this affect heights? This is when the code is being run - I should test when the form actually displays I guess?

Comment: Yep, that was it! Nice chatting! Thanks. Problem with this code is that it only increments offset by the current elements height (not the previous) - which works great when every element is the exact same height but with varying heights it has some overlap